# How do I use code prettifying?

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

I have been to **Help Center → Our Model** and I am unable to figure out how to prettify the Java code snippets in my question. I get the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> to correct the indenting. But exactly what do I add before and after the code, or exactly what do I otherwise do to get the Prettifying?

What would I add to or do with this code snippet to get the coloring? ...

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(
    Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
try {
    Class cmClass = Class.forName(cm.getClass().getName());
    Method method = cmClass.getDeclaredMethod("getMobileDataEnabled");
    method.setAccessible(true);
    mobileDataEnabled = (Boolean)method.invoke(cm);
} 
catch (Exception e) {
    t.setText(e.getMessage());
    t.show();
}
```

Comment: BTW: This has nothing to do with stack snippets, which are only for javascript+html+css.

Comment: I spent a few hours this morning trying to find an answer to this question, with no luck. I found references that said to use things like <pre>, <code>, <!-- language-all:lang-java --> but no examples to follow. I tried to use these on the sample code but the preview did not show the wanted result.

It must be simple. I have years of experience from back in the 90s using HTML. I went to the Prettify Google site but again, lots of reference material useful to someone who already knows, but no examples.

Please show me what to do.

Thank you,

***Mick***

Comment: Prettify is often able to guess the programming language in use, but I don't know what parameters it checks. On the flip side: why should Prettify need to guess, when you -- the asker -- *know* what language it is? (At least one sincerly hopes so.) Adding a tag for the correct language removes the guesswork.

Comment: I did add a Java tag but it did not help. A senior member/moderator prettified the code for me, which is not what i wanted to happen. I need to know how to do it myself. I did try myself to put the tags like  like <pre>, <code>, <!-- language-all:lang-java --> etc around the code but the result was quite bad - the code got deleted or nothing happened.

So i am missing something which i expect is quite simple. But i have not seen any examples to go by, just reference info which certainly would be useful if i could just get this started.

Comment: @Mick Good news! The site provides [excellent revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28522816/revisions) on questions and answers. It looks like someone added the [tag:java] tag for you, which is what enabled the syntax highlighting.

Comment: OK, i finally figured out what went wrong. Cannot press enter while editing, and have to finish up within 5 minutes. Oh well, i'll make up any posts off-line then Copy/Paste them into here. Best to take time to think, plan, and have things right.